# How can i change my icon position and change color when i focus input CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a React project and I need some component, but I can't make it so that when I focus input it changes my icon color. Let me show you my code and CSS. (I must make it with CSS, not with js.)
It's how it looks normally:  (I want that icon in the middle).

[image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9845023?key=c4bc0e7c53c92d53b34f8157b4b2e105]

It's how it looks like when I focus: (I want the icon color to change to red when I focus input).

[image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9845188?key=acfe1c5dc1b3a65a7c7a119191f04143]

HTML:

```
<div className="searchBoxDiv">
    <input className="searchBoxInput" placeholder="Yanıt Ara..." />
    <i className="fa fa-search searchBoxIcon "></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.searchBoxDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* background: transparent; */
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 3%);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.searchBoxDiv:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.295);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.searchBoxInput {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.searchBoxInput:focus {
background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
transition: 0.4s;
border-radius: 5px;
color: rgb(71, 70, 70) !important;
}

.searchBoxIcon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px !important;
  color: #ffffffab;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.searchBoxInput:focus+.searchBoxIcon {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Links you have provided are not working.

Comment: @AdityaSingh thank you for your reply. Im sorry about that. I fixed links. Can you check again please ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's the issue here but when I change the `className` to `class` it works for me. [As you can see](https://codepen.io/pen/yLMmOYR) the text is red on input focus.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine for me. When i focus on the input, the icon color changes to red. And as you wrote you wanna place icon in center, nowadays absolute positioning is old and imperfect way to do that. Rather use flexbox to place that icon in center.

Comment: @Brendan className or class would make no difference here because it is a react code. I think you didn't see that.

Comment: @AdityaSingh I had realized that. I should have been more verbose. What I meant what that by just changing it so it (easily) runs in codepen - it works.